# Python how to find which class owns a variable

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone tell me, whether there is a way to find which class a member variable belongs to, using the variable.

I am trying to create a decorator that will allow only member method and variables of certain classes be used as method parameter.
like

> @acceptmemberofclass(class1,class2)
>   def method(memberfunc, membervar):
>      #do something

I have figured out how to do this with methods (using inspect.getmro(meth.im_class)) but I am unable to find a way for variables

Comment: It's not possible. Values haven't scope or membership concept.

Names have, but in general case multiple names (from multiple scopes) may point to same value. Also check [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: In what context do you *have* this variable you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no "cheap trick" you'll have to have all your class elements and compare their variable values with what you have . (Couldn't comment, sry) At least from what I understand you're trying to achieve, the question isn't very well constructed.